# How do I fire a list var from a DTM direct call?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am trying to fire values into a list var in Adobe Analytics from a DTM direct call but can't seem to get any values to appear.

In my custom code in the direct call rule I have

`cTS = _satellite.getVar('conversionTypeShown');
s.list1 = cTS;`

and the Data Element conversionTypeShown is getting information from the digitalData layer on the page (which is updated just before the direct call)

`if ((digitalData.searchResults !== undefined) && (digitalData.searchResults !== "")) 
{
   return digitalData.otherJobsType + digitalData.searchResults;
}`

I know that these values are being populated correctly because I am firing an eVar with the same data in it (within the same rule) which is coming through OK into Adobe Analytics. But I am not getting any values for the list var?

Does a direct call not allo me to use custom code in this manner?

Any help would be gratefully received.
Owen.

Comment: if you are popping AA as an `s.tl` call and have that code in the custom code section, you also need to "register" your variable in `linkTrackVars`, e.g.  `s.linkTrackVars="list1";`

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Owen. I didn't find this hint in the Adobe documentation.
Finally my code looks like this and works.

```
s.linkTrackVars="list1,list2";
s.list1=_satellite.getVar("FieldsSubmitted");
s.list2=_satellite.getVar("FieldsAborted");
```